# Constructions of PRF (Pseudo Random Function)

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

I was taught only GGM based PRF construction in class. It's very inefficient. I am just curious about various PRF constructions from standard assumptions. Please provide a few PRF constructions from various assumptions.

Comment: Well, one standard assumption is that the SHA-256 compression function is a PRF, from which we can conclude that HMAC-SHA256 is a PRF (and a reasonably efficient one at that), but maybe you meant to restrict the domain of ‘standard assumptions’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common efficient PRFs from specific assumptions are:

The [Naor-Reingold PRF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.618.3884&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which is based on the decision Diffie-Hellman assumption (DDH), and

The [BPR PRF](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/prf-lattice.pdf), which is based on the learning with error assumption (LWE).

Perhaps slightly less well-known is the [NRR PRF](https://omereingold.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/prff.pdf), which is based on the hardness of factoring.